# Compiling Error: unable to open include file

Tags: c

I'm working on xinu and I've changed some `*.c` files: `resched`, `create`, `initiali`, `clkint`. I have also created a header file called `newheader.h` and included it in the source files above like this

```
#include "hewheader.h"
```

The modified `*.c` files and the `newheader.h` (which contains three extern arrays) are saved in a directory called `try` so they have the path: `c:\xinu4win\newsrc\try`

The problem is, when compiling I get this error:

```
 Error: Unable to open include file "newheader.h"
```

Any ideas why?!

[image: error]

Comment: Have you included the directory "newheader.h" is contained in within the include directories?  Or is it at a specific offset from the current location of the file you're referencing it from?

Comment: Is `#include "hewheader.h"` a typo?

Comment: I have included the directory "newheader.h" within the include directories

Comment: did you mean "the modified *.c files and the newheader.h" are saved in a **directory** called "try"?

Comment: yes i ment #include "newheader.h"
I followed the instructions i found for including a new header: 
the recommended practice is to put the new .h in the
dedicated directory (e.g.  XIN4WIN/NEWSRC/exercise) and use the command:

#include "new.h"

Comment: "try" is a directory that i created inside newrsc that contains my files.
my files are saved in "try" directory

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your terminology. Directory files (that contain other files) are normally called directories. Other files (code files, text files etc) are normally called files.

Comment: "try" is a directory @KlasLindbäck

Comment: can you include the full line that you are using to compile?

Comment: Add `-Ic:\xinu4win\newsrc\try` (or whatever directory newheader.h is in) to your compiler options.

Comment: tcc -I.. -c -DTURBOC resched.c > errs          
tcc -I.. -c -DTURBOC initiali.c > errs

Comment: I have edited the question, it now have a picture of compilation, i thought it might clear some things out

Comment: So `newheader.h` resides directly in `c:/xinu4win/newsrc`, correct?

Comment: in c:/xinu4win/newsrc/try @Vorac

Comment: Well, this is very strange then. `#include "newheader.h"` is supposed to look first in the same directory, in which the `.c` is. `tcc` has some enegmatic errors. Try using a different compiler in order to locate the error. Then you can move back to tcc, if need be.

Comment: Solved! the header file's name was too long!

Comment: Don't use Turbo C anymore. They're buggy and non standard

Answer (score 1):

Since from your image you appear to be using DosBox and (ugh!) Turbo C, that means you're running under DOS of some description.

So it will almost certainly still have the 8.3 limit on file names, meaning that `newheader.h` will be too long.

Try shortening it to something that will fit within the confines of your environment, such as `newhdr.h` (both for the file and the `#include`).

Comment: There is no replacement for experience is pickup out the forest-for-the-trees `:)`